# new column based on another column and a value change in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe and I want to create a new column `RESULT` based on column `ID` and `DAT_TIMESTAMP` depending on the value at the `STATUS` column. When `STATUS` value becomes `A` for the first time, I want to get the value at `DAT_TIMESTAMP` and concatenate it with the value of `ID` and keep using the same value of `DAT_TIMESTAMP` for the proceeding rows until the `STATUS` goes back to `A` again.

I hope below sample data helps to explain what I want to do.

```
+--------+--------------+-------+----------------------+
|      ID| DAT_TIMESTAMP| STATUS|                RESULT|
+--------+--------------+-------+----------------------+
| ID_1111| 1617214599502|      D| ID_1111_1617214600304|
| ID_1111| 1617214600002|      D| ID_1111_1617214600304|
| ID_1111| 1617214600502|      A| ID_1111_1617214600502| // first appearance of A
| ID_1111| 1617214601003|      A| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214601503|      A| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214602003|      B| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214602503|      B| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214603004|      C| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214603504|      C| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214604004|      C| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214604504|      C| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214605003|      D| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214605506|      D| ID_1111_1617214600502|
| ID_1111| 1617214606003|      A| ID_1111_1617214606003| // first appearance of A, again
| ID_1111| 1617214606504|      A| ID_1111_1617214606003|
| ID_1111| 1617214607004|      A| ID_1111_1617214606003|
```

I have been trying to do it using `when` function but I am just really unsure what I am doing. Can this be done in spark? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you looking for a solution in Python or in Scala? Your question has both tags

Comment: hi @werner, thanks. either solution for spark or pyspark may serve me, now I removed pyspark to focus on scala side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally did it, maybe not the most elegant or best way to do it...

I can confirm if value in `STATUS` column becomes `A` for the first time by creating an intermediate column containing the previous value of `STATUS` using `lag` function. Then comparing if current value is `A` and previous value is not `A`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// load data...


// add new column
val df2 = df.orderBy("ID", "DAT_TIMESTAMP")
            .withColumn("RESULT",
                last(
                    when(
                        $"STATUS"==="A" &&

                        // intermediate column for comparison
                        lag($"STATUS", 1).over(Window.orderBy("ID", "DAT_TIMESTAMP")).notEqual("A"),

                        concat_ws("_", $"ID", $"DAT_TIMESTAMP"))
                    .otherwise(null), true)
                .over(Window.orderBy("ID", "DAT_TIMESTAMP")))
            .select("*")
```

df2 will be like below. First two rows of `RESULT` is `null` since there is no previous reference to `A`.

```
df2.show(false)

+-------+-------------+------+---------------------+
|ID     |DAT_TIMESTAMP|STATUS|RESULT               |
+-------+-------------+------+---------------------+
|ID_1111|1617214599502|D     |null                 |
|ID_1111|1617214600002|D     |null                 |
|ID_1111|1617214600502|A     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214601003|A     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214601503|A     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214602003|B     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214602503|B     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214603004|C     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214603504|C     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214604004|C     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214604504|C     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214605003|D     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214605506|D     |ID_1111_1617214600502|
|ID_1111|1617214606003|A     |ID_1111_1617214606003|
|ID_1111|1617214606504|A     |ID_1111_1617214606003|
|ID_1111|1617214607004|A     |ID_1111_1617214606003|
+-------+-------------+------+---------------------+
```